# jquery touch punch resize works in all browsers apart from Chrome

Tags: jquery, ios, google-chrome, resizable, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I am using touch punch to enable drag and resize via touch on controls. The drag works fine in all browsers on deskptop, IOS tablets, and Android tablets.

However the resize function only works in Safari, IE, and Firefox on desktop. And it only works on windows tablets in IE. It does not work in Chrome on a deskptop or on any other tablet on any browser.

For Chrome on desktop and tablets the function for resizing is fired but when I go to drag my finger to increase the size of the control being resized the resize stops instantly.

On an ipad the area around the resizable control is highlighted whenever I attempt a resize.

I have looked around but been unable to find an answer to my problem. If any code is needed let me know and I'll post it.